# how to read a kml file on java

Tags: java, xml, kml

If I switch it to xml it works fine but to kml nothing. thought it was basically the same thing,probably missing something silly, or messed it up completly sorry for inconvience but help is much appreciated. basically just trying to read a kml file data on java.

package mysqlcon;

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class ReadXMLFile {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

    File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Users/D/Desktop/mysql/mappedv.kml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("mappedv");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


            System.out.println("coordinates : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("coordinates").item(0).getTextContent());

        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you get any error/exception?

Comment: Do you get any error or undesired behavior?

Comment: no it runs no errors just dosent display data

Comment: Recommend using a Java library that parses KML such as [JAK](https://labs.micromata.de/projects/jak.html) or [GIScore](https://github.com/OpenSextant/giscore).